# On Window Resize, Only Fire Event Once

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I'm trying to change how some interactive content is handled across various screen sizes. On small screens this content should display using [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() <= 845) {
        $(".content").slick({
            centerMode: true,
            slidesToShow: 1
        });
    } else if ($(window).width() > 845) {
        $('.content').slick("unslick");
    }
});
```

This causes slick to be called every time the window is resized to a width below 845 which causes problems. I attempted using `one()` but this doesn't allow for resizing above 845, then back down.

How can I change this so if a user resizes below 845, Slick is called once and is not called again if the window is again resized and meets the `<= 845` condition?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use a variable to control slick behavior.  Essentially when you run the slick the first time, you set the variable to true.  And you use that variable as part of your check to call slick.

```
var runSlick = true
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() <= 845 && runSlick) {
        $(".content").slick({
            centerMode: true,
            slidesToShow: 1
        });
        runSlick = false;
    } else if ($(window).width() > 845) {
        $('.content').slick("unslick");
        runSlick = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this one:

```
var isResizedOnce = false;
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() <= 845) {
        if(!(isResizedOnce)){
            $(".content").slick({
                centerMode: true,
                slidesToShow: 1
            });
        }
        else{
            isResizedOnce = true;
        }
    } else if ($(window).width() > 845) {
        $('.content').slick("unslick");
    }
});
```

In this code, I'm using flag **isResizedOnce** which gets set to true once the window is resized below 845 and based on this the operation is performed.

Comment: Your code does not account for resizing to large and back to small all over again.